# Create a repository from github to team service without using visual studio nor a command

Tags: github, azure-devops

Is there anyway to create a repository from github to Team Service without first cloning the project on local computer then upload it to Team Service? (As in doing everything using web applications (team service online))

Comment: There's an API for VSTS for Git repos here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories - this question is a bit broad.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to import github repo to VSTS directly. And yes, it’s possible. Detail steps as below:

In VSTS team project -> Code tab -> Import reposirory.

[image]

Then select the source type as git -> input the repo URL on github -> input the repo name you want it to display on VSTS -> Import.

[image]

Now the github repo is imported to VSTS.